# Navigating back to tabbed page from content page using shell in MAUI app

Tags: c#, .net, xaml, xamarin, maui

I am new to MAUI, using shell to handle the navigation, and struggle with this simple scenario: my main page is a tabbed page and has a button that redirects to another ContentPage (called AnotherPage in the included code) and which is not tabbed:

```
Shell.Current.GoToAsync("//AnotherPage");
```

My AppShell.xml looks like this:

```
<TabBar>
    <Tab>
        <ShellContent ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:MainPage}"/>
    </Tab>
    <Tab>
        <ShellContent ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:OtherTabbedPage}"/>
    </Tab>
</TabBar>
<ShellContent ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:AnotherPage}" Route="AnotherPage" />
```

That page has an exit button, and its expected behavior is to redirect to the main page, exactly as what happens when the app launches. To do so it has a command that binds to the following code:

```
Shell.Current.GoToAsync("MainPage");
```

But when executed I get the following exception:

> Global routes currently cannot be the only page on the stack, so absolute routing to global routes is not supported.

My routes are registered like so, in the AppShell.xaml.cs file:

```
    Routing.RegisterRoute("MainPage", typeof(MainPage));
    Routing.RegisterRoute("OtherPage", typeof(OtherPage));
    Routing.RegisterRoute("AnotherPage", typeof(AnotherPage));
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks for any insight

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may register the route in ShellContent objects

```
<TabBar Route="MainTabBar">
    <Tab Title="page1" >
        <ShellContent ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:MainPage}" Route="MainPage"/>
    </Tab>
    <Tab Title="page2"> 
        <ShellContent ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:OtherTabbedPage}" Route="OtherTabbedPage"/>
    </Tab>
</TabBar>
<ShellContent ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:AnotherPage}" Route="AnotherPage" />
```

And no need to register them in code-behind again.

Then perform navigation:

```
Shell.Current.GoToAsync("//AnotherPage");
```

or

```
Shell.Current.GoToAsync("//MainTabBar");
```

For more info, you may refer to [Register routes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/fundamentals/shell/navigation#register-routes) and [Perform navigation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/fundamentals/shell/navigation#perform-navigation)

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thank you for your reply, using an absolute route to navigate to MainPage "//MainPage" was what I needed indeed and also I forgot to register my tab bar as a route like so <TabBar Route="MainTabBar"> and now navigating to MainTabBar shows MainPage and the bottom bar as desired

Comment: Glad it helps! I made some changes to add a route for Tab as your said. Please consider accepting the answer if it is helpful.

Answer (score 1):

For anybody running into similar issues, as Liqun Shen-MSFT suggested, first I cleaned my route definitions and defined them only once in AppShell.xaml:

```
<TabBar Route="MainTabBar">
    <Tab>
        <ShellContent ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:MainPage}"/>
    </Tab>
    <Tab>
        <ShellContent ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:OtherPage}"/>
    </Tab>
</TabBar>
<ShellContent ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:AnotherPage}" Route="AnotherPage" />
```

What I was lacking here is the **Route="MainTabBar"** information, that not allows me, from AnotherPage, to navigate to MainPage, with the bottom tab bar and no return button as when the app launches, like so

```
Shell.Current.GoToAsync("//MainTabBar");
```